# Abnormal behaviour of "ng-click" angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I'm trying to create a button that will call a function in the controller. My controller is called with VM...

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <form name="loginForm">
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input required name="username" ng-model="vm.user.username">
            <div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </form>
    <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="vm.userLogin(username)" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">Login
        </md-button>

        <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="registerme=true" >Register
        </md-button>
    </md-card-actions>
</md-content>
```

the problem is with the "userLogin" function that is not called. The rest of the HTML part has others ng-click call like:

```
   <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="vm.submitUserData()" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit
</md-button>
```

and this works fine.
Those are the functions called in the controller

```
function submitUserData() {
    alert(vm.user.username);
    // POST /users
    baseUsers.post(vm.user).then(function (resp,newUser) {
        var pref = vm.preferenze;
        // Ridirigo la navigazione alla pagina "recommendation" passando come parametri le raccomandazioni calcolate e l' id dell utente
        $state.go('form.recommendation',{recommendations:resp,userId: vm.user.id,preferences: pref,iteration: 1});
        }, function (){//resp)
        });
}

function userLogin(username) {
    alert("dbdbdb");
    alert(username);
}
```

I'm losing my head trying to figure it out why it doesn't call the alert function. I tryied either to move the button in the page but nothing change. 
Thanks to everyone who is gonna help me.

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: Is the `username` available in the view ? or should it be `ng-click="vm.userLogin(vm.user.username)"`

Comment: @VinodBhavnani no one

Comment: Yes, that could be the problem. @GabyakaG.Petrioli

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli i tryied even to call just `ng-click="vm.userLogin()"` to see if the alert are going to be called anyway but no way to make it work

Comment: Check whether you don't have variable or anything defined as `userLogin` other than the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is simply confusing you. If you have "controller as" syntax, then make sure that all inner functions are part of that controller.

Firstly, your function `vm.userLogin(username)` should be `vm.userLogin(vm.user.username)`

Secondly, the function **within the controller** should be written differently:

```
vm.userLogin = function(username) {
    alert("dbdbdb");
    alert(username);
}
```

Where `vm` is your scope assignment, e.g. `var vm = this;`, but you can replace it with `$scope.userLogin = function(username){...}`

Comment: IT WORKS ! i dont understand why, the other function was called as i wrote and it works too, can u explain me why i had to change from `function userLogin...` to `vm.userLogin=function()` ?

Comment: To "why it works": without binding it to scope, you would have a _private_ function; in angular's Model-View-Controller, data-binding reflect on changes of your scope (_public_ function). To "why other functions worked": is hard to say, you can probably bind it differently without noticing as `vm.submitUserData = submitUserData;`

Comment: Really helpfoul man, i havent notice that i had a epression as `vm.submitUserData = submitUserData` , appreciated a lot your explanation